# remote server monitoring without public ip

Tags: raspberry-pi, monitoring, nat

Hello I have a set of raspberry pi installed on a client location. The RPis has internet access but not public ip. I was looking for an opensource solution to monitoring the devices some kind of software that can be instaled to send information to a cloud server about system health, uptime and such things.

Its not possible to install a vpn no get access to the raspberrys installed on the client or any kind of network solutions. The Rpis has internet access but cannot be accessed from outside

Comment: Why can't your PI connect to a VPN that you have access to?

Comment: The client dont want a vpn installed on the devices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Icinga2 is also able to handle this configuration. [Sattelite Icinga2 system](https://docs.icinga.com/icinga2/latest/doc/module/icinga2/chapter/distributed-monitoring) can execute tests on the sattelite host (Raspberry) and send test results to the central monitoring host. It is also able to pull its configuration from the central monitoring host.

Although I like Icinga very much, I still feel that learning Icinga2 only to monitor just one Raspberry can be probably an overkill.

Comment: there are 37 raspberry currently deployed :D I will take a look on this sounds promising, thanks

Answer (score 0):

With monitoring tools like nagios you can also use passive checks. Since your RPI can connect to the internet it could send check results to your nagios/icinga/shinken/... server. Your monitoring server would raise an alarm if it's not getting any data from the RPI in a defined period.

See: [nagios passive checks](https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagioscore/docs/nagioscore/3/en/passivechecks.html)